Why TimeConstrained does not work when increasing the time?
I found a case where in V 14.4 TimeConstrained hangs when increasing the time from 60 seconds to 120 seconds.
This happens only in V 14.0. Same exact code works in V 13.3 on same PC and on same ode.
Why is that? And is there a way to make it work with 120 seconds or higher?
This is all on windows 10 with 120 GB RAM.
code
ode = (1 + y'[x]^2)^2 == y[x]^2 y''[x]
ic = {y[0] == 3, y'[0] == Sqrt[2]}
res = TimeConstrained[DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x], 120]

hangs on V 14. I can wait 10 minutes and nothing happens. Task manager shows Mathematica running at very high CPU all the time.
In addition Abort evaluation does nothing. I have to kill the kernel to get out of the hang.
Changing the time from 120 to 60 now it time out OK and no kernel hang.
These times might be different for you. But basically smaller time it works OK. But longer time it hangs. So you can change the actual times on your end if 120 does not cause hang for you.
This for me this is very serious problem, since I have time limit on each call to DSolve and Integrate and these always worked in Mathematica.
This is first time I see Mathematica hang on TimeConstrained.
Do others see this and is there a workaround other than making the time constrained small?

It looks like some portion of the computation ends up in a third-party library which is not interruptible, or at least not be default.

Perhaps one of SetSystemOptions[   "PolynomialAlgebraOptions" -> "FLINTInterruptible" -> True]; or SetSystemOptions["PolynomialAlgebraOptions" -> "UseFLINT" -> False]; would help.
